# How to limit results per page in Yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

How can I limit the results of data each page in Yajra datatables? Currently I'm using the code below:

**Controller**

```
return Datatables::of(collect($results))->make(true);
```

The `$results` variable is just an array of data from database.

**JS**

```
$('table.dataTableAjax').DataTable({
     "processing": true, // Make this true, to show the "Processing" word while loading
     "serverSide": true,
     "paging": true,
     "pageLength": 10,
     "ordering": false, // Make this false, to disable sorting
     "ajax": "..."
});
```

**Example data from server**

```
{
    "data":[
        { "name": "Bob", "Age": 30 },
        { "name": "Billy", "Age": 33 },
        { "name": "Megan", "Age": 31 }
    ]
}
```

So for example, the first page should load 10 rows, next page 10 rows again, and so on. But what's happening is it loads the 5000+ rows, and just cutting them into 10 table rows in client side which affects the performance of the application. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of pulling all the results, try to limit the results in your controller.

Comment: Already tried that using `limit(10)`, but it only gives me 10 results and the pagination has only `1 page`.

Comment: Could you share what the `$results` are ?

Comment: @linktoahref please check my update

Comment: I'm sorry, but I meant your controller code. Have you tried the Eloquent Query Builder way instead of the collection ?

Comment: if you inspect the network console do you see http request trying to fetch the next page when you click on the next page button ?

Comment: This could be helpful https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1575

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110665/limit-of-displaying-rows-in-datatables/23111244 

refer this

Comment: Are you using the  Query Builder for getting data from database or Eloquent Model 
try to use Query Builder in that case only one time you got the data even when your working with pagination the ajax does not call @Jonjie

Comment: This might also be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022316/how-do-i-paginate-a-collection-or-custom-query-into-api-json-in-laravel/45022317#45022317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up by just adding these code below, and not using yajra for the functionality.

```
$limit = request('length');
$start = request('start');

$query->offset($start)->limit($limit);

return response()->json([
    "draw" => intval(request('draw')),  
    "recordsTotal"    => intval(User::count()),  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($total_filtered),
    "data" => $results
]);
```

Everything works fine, and loads faster. I didn't notice that datatables actually throws requests to the laravel end point (route).

Comment: Hello @Jie, how did you manage to get `total_filtered` parameter ?

Comment: @skywalskurt by counting the result of the query after some conditions.

Answer (score -1):

this is working for me and shorter code

```
return Datatables::of($data)->setTotalRecords(500)->make(true);
```

`setTotalRecords()` is a best answer for your looking for